# How can I prevent my form for future edit?

Tags: angular, angular5

In my form page, after the user filling all the data, I am taking to next page. works fine. But there is a `edit` button the new page, when user clicks it, I need get him back with the form page, as well the forms datas are filled. ( previously what he filled up )

I tried with :

```
 goToQuoteForm(){
      console.log('back called');
       // this.location.back();
       // window.history.back();
       // this.router.navigate(['quote'], { skipLocationChange: true });
    }
```

all above 3 is not works at all. what is the correct way to prevent the current page with all it's status to previous requirement. any one help me to understand and implement the correct approach for `angular 5.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to write a service which stores the data in it.
You would have to inject this service in both the form page and in the next page.

1. Whenever the user goes from the formpage to the next page you would have to send the data to the service to save it.
2. Everytime the formpage get called you need to check in the constructor if the service has any data to put those back in the form